# Regarding leasing removal

Tags: united-states, rental-property, credit-history, real-estate-leasing

I am living in shared accommodation. I am a student and not working yet so I don't have a SSN. But due to some reason I want to move out from apartment and my name is also on the lease, so I need all of my roommates to sign removal from lease. What if I sign removal of me, and other roommates don't sign? Would it hurt my credit history even without SSN?